# Scanner next() - how to replace line breaks [java]

Tags: java, arrays, newline, replaceall

I have hit the wall!

After reading alot of interesting threads on StackOverflow, I have tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Let's assume I have a .txt-file where I want to replace line breaks with "XXX". I use a count-method to count the lines in the document.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner("document.txt);

String [] textToArray = new String[count];

for(int i = 0; textToArray.length; i++){
String text = reader.nextLine();

text = text.replaceAll("\n", "XXX");
textToArray[i] = text;

}
```

I then use a for each loop to print out the text. The output is still the same as the original.

I have also tried "\n", "\r", "\r" even "\r\n".

Comment: It's because you read it line by line without reading the newline character.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! Is there anyway to work around it? A different approach, that may be?

Comment: To come up with a different approach, please state what you want to do ;) Do you want to have those lines in an array or a single String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, **excluding any line separator at the end**. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

So, you're reading the text of each line, but you will not see the `\r` and/or `\n` characters.

Since you're reading each line into an array, you should just append `XXX` to each value:

```
for (int i = 0; textToArray.length; i++) {
    String text = reader.nextLine();
    textToArray[i] = text + "XXX";
}
```

---

**Unrelated**

I would also suggest that you read into a `List`, instead of an array. You can always convert to array afterwards.

And I hope you remember to close the `Scanner`, and that you showed mock code, because `new Scanner("document.txt")` will scan the text `document.txt`, not the content of a file by that name.

```
String[] textToArray;
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("document.txt"))) {
    List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String text; (text = reader.nextLine()) != null; ) {
        textList.add(text + "XXX");
    }
    textToArray = textList.toArray(new String[textList.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you solution! I got super excited and forgot to answer! I had tried this solution, but after reading this, it made much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = reader.nextLine();

text = text.replaceAll("\n", "XXX");
```

When you read a line, there will be no line break for the replace all to trigger. You will have whatever line you read at that point in text.

Try building a string or placing the full text in a String and then replace the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to replace "\n" with XXX in the example given? It would be musch easier to read to entire file to one string like so:

```
String file = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and then you can use a built in function such as:

```
String replace(char oldChar, char newChar);
```

This will return a new string containing your file,  with all the spaces replaced with XXX. Or whatever character you wish to use there.